# optimize array with only 3 distinct values? How to design?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance, optimization

I am trying a resource insensitive functionality in C++. I am implementing an array which has 10000 records but any record will have only possible 3 values i.e. 0,1,2. So i was wondering  instead of storing memory for 10000 instance all 3 together if some how I can just save one instance of each and manage logically. Not sure how exactly to implemenet.

For example my array would be something like this.

{1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2,.............}

we might go for more than 10000 records too

Comment: An array of 3 representing the `count` of each of 0, 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @KingsIndian I did not get it, please describe..

Comment: You need to clarify that. Better with an example, describing the record, its values and what you're trying to achieve with all that.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Edites question with example of data..

Comment: You want to optimize for space. The question is how much performance you're willing to sacrifice for it.

Comment: It depends for what purpose you want to store the values whether you need to know the sequence of numbers. If you just need the number of 0s, 1s and 2s then simply use `arr[3]`.

Comment: @Dialecticus I am in resource in constraint, if you can guide me to both scenario.. one with low memory use, and other with high performance it will help. I will test both and get best deal for functionality

Comment: Sorry, no code from me. Answer from Jon Skeet is good enough for me with space reduction to 25% (minus the code). Packing to base 3 instead to base 4 is also a good suggestion from him, if you really need space reduction to 20% (minus the code). If you need more reduction then you could use some compression algorithm, but only if that algorithm is already available, because the code for it would probably be larger than the space that it needs to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could just create an array of 2500 bytes, with 4 values per byte (each value takes 2 bits). Access any single value using bit-shifting/masking. I suspect that's going to be simpler than a scheme which groups the values, and will be more "array-like" for access. Of course, it's hard to say for sure as we don't know what you need to do with the values.

You could *actually* fit 5 values into each byte (as 3<sup>5</sup> is 243) so you'd only need a byte array of size 2000... but the access code would be somewhat trickier. I would resist this extra complexity unless you *really* need it.

Additionally, if the values are relatively sparse - e.g. almost everything is 0, with just a few 1s and 2s - then you could obviously store that more efficiently.

EDIT: Okay, so I haven't done any C++ for a long time, but it would be something like:

```
// Entirely untested. Please test thoroughly, and make sure you understand it
// before using it.
int get_value(unsigned index)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    unsigned raw_index = index / 4;
    unsigned index_within_byte = (index % 4) * 2;

    return (array[raw_index] >> index_within_byte) & 3;
}

void set_value(unsigned index, int value)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    unsigned raw_index = index / 4;
    unsigned index_within_byte = (index % 4) * 2;

    int mask = 0xff ^ (3 << index_within_byte);
    array[raw_index] = (array[raw_index] & mask) | (value << index_within_byte);
}
```

EDIT: Thinking about it further, you might even want to create an array of `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` instead of bytes, and put 16 or 32 "real" values into each array element. I suspect that on most processors that may make for more efficient memory access.

Comment: i concur. some offset-math, masking, and bit-shifting will make this about the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @CraigNelson not clear on hoe to implement "offset-math, masking, and bit-shifting".. An example will help a lot.

Comment: @JonSkeet how to do this bit-shifting/masking?

Comment: @Pritesh: I was editing my answer. I haven't tried this code at all, but it should at least give you the gist of it. Do you *definitely* need this? If you're uncomfortable with somewhat-low-level operations like this, you're not really in a good position to write performance-critical code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: lol. nice disclaimer =P. If he doesn't get it he prolly won't use it, but it was the first thing I thought of as well, so I'm at least in good company.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am .Net programmer for last 6 years.. but suddenly need to something very performance critical.. so learning on the job. High end data structure of .Net did not helped me here..

Comment: @Pritesh: You'd do *exactly* the same thing in C#.

Comment: I've been a core C+ systems engineer for 20+ years, so we're about as polar opposite as they come. All the more reason I laugh that we both hit the same solution to this question. btw. nothing immediately springs as wrong in the code above, so your retention is good .

Comment: We've been talking about this answer for a few minutes in the C++ room. There's a few things you might wanna fix, but we'll cut you some slack since you're not in C++ :D 1) `3 << index_within_byte` is undefined behavior if it shifts into the sign-bit and overflows. So change it to `(unsigned)3 << index_within_byte`. 2) The rest of the `int`s would probably be better off as `unsigned`. Though it'd be better if they used `uint32_t` or another fixed-integer type for complete portability.

Comment: @Mysticial: How would `3 << index_within_byte` overflow if `index_within_byte` is only going to be 0, 2, 4 or 6 due to the way it's created? Feel free to edit for appropriate types though.

Comment: Oh right, it's within the byte. I didn't look far up enough to see that it doesn't go all the way to `30`.

Comment: @JonSkeet understood and tried it... also checked performance counter.. very good solution.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make a vector of `std::pair<int, int>`, such that, `first` of the pair, contains 0, 1, or 2 and `second` contains the number of times that particular element has been seen.

So for your example

> {1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2,.............}

you can store it like

> {<1, 1>, <0, 2>, <1, 1>, <2, 1>, <1, 3>, <0, 1>, <2, 2>, <0, 3>, <2, ...>...}

You can see it is good only when there are lots of contiguous repetition, and if you don't need direct access.